# Read from Binary file issue

Tags: c, file, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i,j;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("./pathto/sth.bmp","rb");
    fread(&i,1, 1, f);
    printf("%d ",i);
    fread(&j,1, 1, f);
    printf("%d ",j);

  return 0;
}
```

I want to read the first 2 values from a bmp file. I know that they are 66 and 77 . The problem is that if i read only the first value the variable "i" becomes 66 which is good. But if i read the second value , as "j" , then "j" becomes 77 which is good , and "i" takes a random value something like 196540 and i don't understand why. So if i read the first value everything is ok. If i read the first 2 values, the last value is good, but the first modifies, it becomes a random one , sth like 196540

Comment: Why are you using `int` variables when you're reading `byte` sized values? What is `sizeof(int)` on the platform you're using?

Comment: I suspect reading `unsigned char sig[2]` via `fread(sig, sizeof(sig), 1, f)` would be nearer to what you seem to want, though you probably want to take the time to read the [entire header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) carefully.

Comment: the should be checking the returned values (not the parameter values from calls to `fopen()` and `fread()` to assure the operation(s) were successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try your program I get garbage results for both variables.

The problem is that you're using the wrong type variables. You're reading a single byte from the file, but you're reading it into an `int` variable, which is multiple bytes. So this combines the single byte from the file with whatever random data happens to be in the initial values of the variables.

Declare them as `char` instead of `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i,j;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("sth.bmp","rb");
    fread(&i,1, 1, f);
    printf("%d ",i);
    fread(&j,1, 1, f);
    printf("%d\n",j);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,that was the problem, i tried something similar before, but i was modifying  the arguments of printf too (%s instead of %d) why is not this good ?

Comment: `%s` is for printing a string, which is an array of `char` ending with a null byte. `i` is just a single character. If you want to see the character instead of the ASCII code, use `%c`.

Comment: @LazuRazvan: note that printing out the character instead of its decimal value is only useful for the very first 2 bytes in a BMP file. The rest is all binary data.